# Find functions $f$ and $g$ so that $f(x)g'(x)=f'(x)g(x)$ but $g(x)\neq kf(x)$ with $k\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: functions, puzzle

These are 2 not-working examples:

Obviously, if $f=g$, then $g(x)=1f(x)$ so there is exists $k\in\mathbb{R}$

$f(x)=0.5x², g(x)=2x²$, then $0.5x²\cdot 4x=2x³=x\cdot2x²$, but $g(x)=4f(x)$, so there exists a $k\in\mathbb{R}$ again

etc. I got this puzzle from a friend of mine, and he told me it is solvable, but he also told me it's not that easy. I think, f and g cannot be polynomials, I don't have a concrete proof, neither can I explain why, but it's just a very strong feeling. It has to be something a little more complicated. Does someone have a tip? I'm gonna test some sine functions now. The function may not be a piecewise-defined function, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a good friend.

An answer could be like this: $f(x) = \begin{cases}
x^2, \forall x \geq 0;\\
-x^2, \forall x \leq 0;
\end{cases}$ and $g(x) = x^2$.

Comment: @Downvoter Please explain the downvote.

Comment: Hmm, sorry, it's not the answer I was looking for... The solution has to be a "normal" function and not a piecewise-defined function, but I guess I should have specified it right from the beginning, that's my fault.

Comment: There is no solution in "normal" functions simply because the derivative of $\frac g f$ is $0$, which means $\frac g f$ is at least locally constant. Any nontrivial solution is therefore piecewise-defined by nature (or equivalent to such, e.g. $f(x)=|x^3|$ and $g=x^3$).